# WPF - Displaying 'TextChanged' Event results in ListBox as new ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF form with a textbox and a listbox. I also have an ObvervableCollection that is populated with names. In my 'textChanged' event, I am instantiating a new ObservableCollection by making a comparison with what is typed in the textbox. In WinForms, I am able to create a list of matches which I then populate a listbox with. I cannot figure this out in WPF. It seems I have the databinding correct; however, I feel like I need to make a reference in the .cs file to the listbox perhaps.

Please let me know what I might be missing. Thank you.

xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> NameList1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> NewNameList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        NameList1 = new ObservableCollection<string>(){"foo", "man", "chu", "spam"};
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // constructing a new observable collection to match with the above observable collection
        // logic is good, but no data is added to the listBox
        NewNameList =
            new ObservableCollection<string>(NameList1.Where(n => n.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())));
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ObservableDatabindingExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ObservableDatabindingExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="125*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="72*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="45,47,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding NewNameList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="45,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your binding is working correctly as you said.
However, when you're assigning a new reference to `NewNameList` the view wont notice it.
What you were trying to achieve may have worked until this point, since `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and thereby notifies the view when changes are made to the items of the collection.

To get the effect you want to achieve, you will have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and invoke the `PropertyChanged` event with the name of your collection upon assigning a new reference to it.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> NameList1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> NewNameList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        NameList1 = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "foo", "man", "chu", "spam" };
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // constructing a new observable collection to match with the above observable collection
        // logic is good, but no data is added to the listBox
        NewNameList =
            new ObservableCollection<string>(NameList1.Where(n => n.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())));

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(NewNameList)));
    }
}
```